# Testing Android apps on PC - is it reliable?

Tags: android, testing, functional-testing

I was asked to test some Android apps, but I do not have any andoid device currently. There are a loads of different Android emulators and/or dev frameworks, so I was wondering if tests performed on such virtual system is reliable in terms of later work on actual devices?

Can I use these emulators for test purposes without testing on any actual device? What are strategies for such tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use emulators.
Of course, Eclipse and Android Studio has there own, but I would recommend you [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) as faster one.